# Use graphing calculator to find vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am trying to use my TI-84 Plus CE to find an efficient way to calculate the cross product of two vectors. Along the way I stumbled upon some interesting pieces of math and have some questions. I learnt how to use determinants of matrices to compute the cross product, however my calculator cannot return a the determinant in this form for example:

[image]

I tried to use 1, 1, 1 instead of i , j and k and this as expected returns only the sum of all the vector components. I am asking if anyone knows

a) A way to get the cross product without summing up the individual components ( I tried to use *i* instead of 1 but that did not work)

b) If there is another way to quickly compute cross product.

**Some other notes**

- A quick way to verify if the answer to the cross products is correct is to multiply them with the individual components to get the dot product and check if both are zero.
- The Ti-84 Graphing Calculator is not able to handle complex numbers in matrices

Comment: I think plugging in 6 numbers to the component function is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: There is no built in function for the cross product, but here is a link to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ii1dDPq1Vjo) showing you how to write a program to do that.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thanks for the video

Comment: @RobertTheTutor May I ask what that is?

Comment: I simply meant that using your overt formula $(a_2b_3-a_3b_2, a_3b_1-a_1b_3,a_1b_2-a_2b_1)$ is by far the most direct approach.